# how do I use the variable from a For loop outside the loop in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, variables, for-loop

So I am a bit rusty in my programming skills and don't have any real world experience except for the college classes I have taken in the past. I am working on a program for a class but running into a snag;I cannot figure out how to use the value of a variable inside a `For` loop outside of the loop. Here is the code I am referencing:

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int want, have, need;
int counter = 0;

char response, cont;

int diff(int want, int have);

int main(){
cout << "Welcome!\n";
cout << "This program will help you reach your money saving goals!\n";
cout << "Would you like to use this program? (y/n)\n";
    cin >> response;
    while (response == 'y'){
        cout << "Please enter all amounts in whole dollars only!\n";
        cout << "Please enter the amount of money you would like to have saved: $";
        cin >> want;
        cout << "\nPlease enter the amount of money you currently have saved: $";
        cin >> have;
        if (have >= want){
            cout << "You have already reached or exceeded your goal, this program will not be able to help you!\n";
            system("Pause");
            return 0;
        }
        cout << "\nYou need to save $" << diff(want, have) << " more money to reach your goal!\n";
        cout << "Would you like me to help you with a savings plan?";
        cin >> cont;
        while (cont == 'y'){
            int menu;
            cout << "Please select from the following options: \n";
            cout << "1 - Daily Saving Plan\n";
            cout << "2 - Weekly Saving Plan\n";
            cout << "3 - Monthly Saving Plan\n";
            cout << "Enter the number associated with your choice: \n";
            cin >> menu;

            switch (menu){
                case 1: {
                    int daily;
                    cout << "You have chosen the Daily Savings Plan\n";
                    cout << "How much money can you save every day? $";
                    cin >> daily;
                    for (int x = daily; x < need; x++){
                        daily = daily + daily;
                        counter++;
                    }
                    cout << "\nIt will take you " << counter << " days to reach your goal!\n";
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    int weekly;
                    cout << "You have chosen the Weekly Savings Plan\n";
                    cout << "How much money can you save every week? $";
                    cin >> weekly;
                    for (int x = weekly; x < need; x++){
                        counter++;
                    }
                    cout << "\nIt will take you " << counter << " weeks to meet your goal!\n";
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    int monthly;
                    cout << "You have chosen the Monthly Savings Plan\n";
                    cout << "How much money can you save every month? $";
                    cin >> monthly;
                    for (int x = monthly; x < need; x++){
                        monthly = monthly + monthly;
                        counter++;
                    }
                    cout << "\nIt will take you " << counter << " months to reach your goal!\n";
                    break;

                }
                default: cout << "You made an invalid selection";

                    cout << "Would you like to look at a different saving plan? (y/n)\n";
                    cin >> cont;
            }
        }
    }
}

int diff(int want, int have){
return want - have;
}
```

So, when I run the program, everything runs ok, but the value of counter is always shown as "0" in the final `cout` statement.

I understand why it is doing this, I think..and it's because of the "int counter = 0" declaration outside the loop, so I assume it goes back to that value after the loop exits.

If I do not initiate the counter variable, I get an error, and if I declare the value inside the loop, I get an error trying to use it in the cout statement as I have above.

I'm not even sure my for loop is structured correctly...basically I want it to add to itself the weekly variable, until the total of `x = need`. I also want to capture how many iterations it takes for that, then output it as the number of weeks. Hopefully that all makes sense; any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: post code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: No, `counter` won't go back to zero after the loop. If it's zero, then it's because it was never incremented. Check the values of `weekly` and `need` before the loop starts.

Comment: for starters, i would try to declare counter outside switch, at the begining of the function. before the loop starts there should be initialization: counter=0;

Comment: Also, arithmetic like `counter = need>weekly ? need-weekly : 0` might be clearer (and faster) than a loop.

Comment: "so I assume [...]" - one of the biggest mistakes you can make while programming. always verify your assumptions.

Comment: need is a variable from earlier in the program...the assignment requires me to use a for loop, and this is about the only place I can think of to use one. Also, for personal reasons I just want to know how to make it work like this. I didn't think of declaring counter outside the switch, I will try that

Comment: @ChrisJohnson: good job addressing the only comment which was incorrect. *sigh*.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson ``the assignment requires me to use a for loop`` This is a terrible reason to put a for-loop where you can simply directly calculate the value mathematically. Odds are, if this is a requirement, then there is another place somewhere where a for-loop is a logical solution to the problem, not a contrived one. Having said that, as written, the only reason ``counter`` should be ``0`` is if ``x<need`` is true before the loop even runs.

Comment: Just install Visual Studio 5.  It's a built-in "feature" in that version of the C++ compiler that variables declared in the for(xxx;;) part are not scoped to the for loop.

Comment: @Eric the variable in question isn't defined inside the for-loop scope. Also, that seems like a pretty significantly C++-breaking bug.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson Also, you never actually initialize ``need`` to anything (not even `0`). This is undefined behavior, but there is an approximately 50% chance that ``need <= 0`` and thus your for-loops never execute.

Comment: @aruisdante I agree that my reasoning for using a for loop here isn't sound, but I had an idea and chose to run with it, and now I am asking for help. I am in no way a professional programmer and probably never will be, just asking for a little help with this idea of mine for a class :)

Comment: Light bulb....thanks aruisdante, I think I figured out my problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want to do can be done with `ceil(double(need/weekly))` and that rounds up need divided by weekly.

Your declaration outside the loop doesn't affect the value you `cout` after you finished the `for` loop.

As for your problem, it looks like you never initialized `need` so your for loops never made an iteration as undefined is not less than or equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

A sketch in C++11 of your program.

```
char prompt( std::initializer_list<const char*> message, std::initializer_list<const char*> question, std::initializer_list<char> options ) {
  for( auto msg:message )
    std::cout << msg;
  while(true) {
    char response;
    for( auto q:question)
      std::cout << q;
    std::cin >> response;
    for (char option:options) {
      if (response == option)
        return response;
    }
  }
}
int prompt( std::initializer_list<const char*> message, std::initializer_list<const char*> question, int min = 0, int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max() ) {
  for( auto msg:message )
    std::cout << msg;
  while(true) {
    int response;
    for( auto q:question)
      std::cout << q;
    std::cin >> response;
    if (response >= min && response <= max)
      return response;
    }
  }
}
void saving( const char* plan, const char* unit, const char* units, int target ) {
  int daily = prompt(
    {"You have chosen the ", plan,  "\n"},
    {"How much money can you save every ", unit, "? $"}, 
    1 // min saving of 1$ per unit time to prevent infinite loops
  );
  std::cout  << "\n";
  int counter = 0;
  int amount_saved = 0;
  while (amount_saved < target) {
    ++counter;
    amount_saved += daily;
  }
  if (counter != 1)
    std::cout << "It will take you " << counter << " " << units << " to reach your goal\n";
  else
    std::cout << "It will take you " << counter << " " << unit << " to reach your goal\n";
}

int main() {
  while(
    prompt(
      {"Welcome!\nThis program will help you reach your money saving goals!\n"},
      {"Would you like to use this program? (y/n)\n"},
      {'y', 'n'}
    ) == 'y'
  )
  {
    int want = prompt( {"Please enter all amounts in whole dollars only!\n"},
      {"Please enter the amount of money you would like to have saved?"} );
    int have = prompt( {"\n"}, {"Please enter the amount of money you currently have saved?\n"} );
    std::cout << "\n";
    if (have >= want) {
      std::cout << "You win!\n";
      system("Pause"); // ick
      return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "You need to save $" << (have-want) << " more money to reach your goal!\n";
    while( 'y' == prompt(
      {},
      {"Would you like me to help you with a savings plan? (y/n)"},
      { 'y', 'n' }
    )) {
       char menu = prompt(
         {
           "Please select from the following options: \n",
           "1 - Daily Saving Plan\n",
           "2 - Weekly Saving Plan\n",
           "3 - Monthly Saving Plan\n"
         },
         {"Enter the number associated with your choice: \n"},
         { '1', '2', '3' }
       );
       switch (menu) {
         case '1': {
           saving( "Daily Saving Plan", "day", "days", have-want);
         } break;
         case '2: {
           saving( "Weekly Saving Plan", "week", "weeks", have-want);
         } break;
         case '3': {
           saving( "Monthly Saving Plan", "month", "months", have-want);
         } break;
       }

    }
  }
}
```